# What is the R-symmetry group structure?

Tags: group-theory, supersymmetry

I found on some [susy lectures](http://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/susycourse.pdf) (Bertolini, Lectures on Supersymmetry) that R-symmetry definition is:

> The largest possible  internal  symmetry  group  which  can  act  non 
>   trivially  on  the $Q$’s  is  thus $U(N)$,  and  this  is  called  the 
>   R-symmetry  group

So my question is: why the largest is $U(N)$ and not something else?
There are two things that I don't understand

- why it has to be an $N$-dimensional group (complex dimensions)?
- why the structure has to be exactly $U(N)$ and not something else with the same dimension?

I split the two points because the intuitive reason behind the first one has to be "because there are $N$ indices on the supercharges" but I don't know how show that this implies the statement.

On the second point I have no ideas at all.